# 0x800a0005 Error when using OpenAsTextStream

Tags: vbscript

My intention is to write every output line to a log file for archive purposes. Instead of writing to a file using OpenTextFile() and Write(), and then closing at the end of the script, I would like to write to the file as the script executes. If for whatever reason, the script is terminated before it has a chance to close the file, I worry I will lose those logs.

To achieve this, here is what I have attempted:

```
'Master Logs
Dim MasterLogFileName, MasterLogFile, MasterLogFileStream
Const ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = 2

Function Write(text)
    Wscript.StdOut.Write text

    Set MasterLogFileStream = MasterLogFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForAppending, TristateUseDefault)
    MasterLogFileStream.Write text
    MasterLogFileStream.Close
End Function

'Create a Master Log file to write to
MasterLogFileName = "LogFile.log"
fso.CreateTextFile(MasterLogFileName)
Set MasterLogFile = fso.GetFile(MasterLogFileName)

Write("Test writing!")
Write("Test writing 2!")
```

However, I receive the following error:

> 0x800a005 - Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument

On this line:

```
Set MasterLogFileStream = MasterLogFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForAppending, TristateUseDefault)
```

When executing the Write() Function for the second time, using this line:

```
Write("Test writing 2!")
```

Comment: I made sure to define ForAppending and TriStateUseDefault. I've also used ForWriting.

Comment: **1**. As per [OpenAsTextStream Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59(v=vs.84).aspx), use `Const TristateUseDefault = -2`. **2**. Define `fso` object as follows: `set fso = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by Lankymart and JosefZ, the reason this wasn't working was because I specified 2 for TristateUseDefault, instead of -2, as per the [OpenAsTextStream method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59(v=vs.84).aspx) specifies.

Comment: The "reason" is you used `2` instead of `-2` for the value of `TristateUseDefault`.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the answer to reflect yours and JosefZ's answer